# Spring security authentication does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying login with spring security but it does not work. I get a page refresh and nothing happens. 
For example I'll want to go to not permitted page and Sping gives `login.mustache` where I can't do nothing with login form.

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("u")
                        .password("1")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

**login.mustache**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
Login page
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
<a href="/registration">Add new user</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The path `/login` is also registered in the config

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as you wrote, but the problem did not go away

Comment: @Borino. That ceased to be the case some time ago. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login

Comment: @dur sping boot 2.0.5. Yeah, I've got registered controller for `/`. I following this lesson [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

Comment: @dur Here is response. If I understand you correctly - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYXZj.png)

Comment: @dur No, its correctly. I just changed it to not to be confused